# Allocating memory to hold an array of structs in C

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I'm trying to allocate memory to hold an array of structs

```
SERVER* topology = malloc(sizeof(struct SERVER*)* 10 );
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        topology[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct SERVER));
    }
    PATH* paths = malloc(sizeof(struct PATH*)*10);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        paths[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct PATH));
    }
```

These are my structs

```
typedef struct{
    int id;
    char ip_addr[MAX_IP + 1];
    int port;
}SERVER;

typedef struct{
    int server1;
    int server2;
    int weight;
}PATH;
```

And then later in my code I try to free it using

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
   {
     free(paths[i]);
   }
   free(paths);

   for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
   {
     free(topology[i]);
   }
   free(topology);
```

I keep getting the following error

```
error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to an incomplete type 'struct SERVER'
                topology[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct SERVER));
                                     ^     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
:18:42: note: forward declaration of 'struct SERVER'
        SERVER* topology = malloc(sizeof(struct SERVER*)* 10 );
                                                ^
:26:21: error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to an incomplete type 'struct PATH'
                paths[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct PATH));
                                  ^     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
:23:37: note: forward declaration of 'struct PATH'
        PATH* paths = malloc(sizeof(struct PATH*)*10);
```

...........

```
c:97:11: error: passing 'PATH' to parameter of incompatible type 'void *'
         free(paths[i]);
              ^~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/stdlib.h:143:18: note: passing argument to parameter here
void     free(void *);
                    ^
:103:11: error: passing 'SERVER' to parameter of incompatible type 'void *'
         free(topology[i]);
              ^~~~~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/stdlib.h:143:18: note: passing argument to parameter here
void     free(void *);
```

I'm generally new to C. Any help appreciated.

Comment: the type of your struct is `SERVER`, not `struct SERVER`, `SERVER` is a typedef of an anonymous struct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
typedef struct SERVER {
  ....
} SERVER;

typedef struct PATH {
  ....
} PATH;
```

You see, you use `struct SERVER` and `struct PATH` but you haven't declared these. You did declare a type `SERVER` and a type `PATH` using a `typedef` on an unnamed struct.

Alternatively, you could leave your structs as they are, and use `sizeof(PATH*)` and `sizeof(STRUCT*)`.

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues here:

```
SERVER* topology = malloc(sizeof(struct SERVER*)* 10 );
...
PATH* paths = malloc(sizeof(struct PATH*)*10);
```

- You have a type called `SERVER`, which is a typedef of anonymous struct.  You don't have `struct SERVER` defined, so use `SERVER` instead of `struct SERVER`.  The same applies to `PATH`.
- You're allocating space for 10 pointers to `SERVER`, however `topology` is a pointer to `SERVER`, which means it can act as an array of `SERVER`, not an array of `SERVER *`, which is how you're using it.  This is why you're getting an error when calling `free`, since `topology[i]` is a `SERVER`, not a `SERVER *`.  Similarly for `PATH` as well.

For this to work properly, you would need to define `topology` and `paths` as follows:

```
SERVER **topology = malloc(sizeof(SERVER *) * 10 );
PATH **paths = malloc(sizeof(PATH *) * 10);
```

Alternately, instead of allocating an array of pointers, then allocating individual elements, you could instead keep your current definitions and allocate the whole array at once:

```
SERVER *topology = malloc(sizeof(SERVER) * 10);
PATH *paths = malloc(sizeof(PATH) * 10);
```

Then clean up like this:

```
free(topology);
free(paths);
```